# How to avoid selling multiple times a single product

Tags: cart, marketplace

let say I have 10 users with the same product in their basket but the item is only available as one single item like on eBay..

So if all the users pay the product at the same time, how can I avoid selling 10 times this single product ?

I mean, on eBay you have to confirm that you'll buy the item so it freezes (make it available only to you), that solves the problem but if the buyer does not pay after that I would need to bring back the product to the normal state (available).

Any advices ? Thanks

Comment: 1) process 'Out of Stock' as soon as someone buys the product. 2) check stock before customer makes proceeds to checkout

Comment: The payment process can take seconds... during this time another user can be paying too, this is what I try to avoid.